How can I configure Windows Time Service to only sync on demand?
Is there any way to configure the Windows Time Service to ONLY perform a sync when a w32tm /resync is explicitly issued?
i.e. no other periodic polling/syncing or clock adjustments to be performed at any other time. Only when explicitly requested.
Background: One of the risk-control measures for our system states that the system clock MUST NOT be altered while the system is in operation (due to the risk of upsetting badly-written timing code in software that we can not change!).
However we'd still like to keep the clock roughly in sync with our private NTP server. So my intention is to call w32tm /resync from a Scheduled Task at login, before the rest of our system starts. Which works, but it still attempts periodic syncs after that.

Does calling that command start the windows time service? (I don't have a test box atm) but if it does then you could just try scripting a stop on the time service after the 'manual' sync and before your other services/system starts

The w32tm /resync command requires Windows Time Service to be started before it is run. I can't stop the service after the resync as our architecture requires other child clients to my system.

how about a triggered job to block the port (123) on the local firewall once you have done your initial sync?
